# Update plot scatter with connecting line plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using an update plot function to make a simulation of Mars and Earths orbit using Matplotlib, but I'm trying to make a line connecting the two so it can describe the retrograde motion of Mars.
How would I add the plt.plot() function in the _update_plot?

```
def _update_plot(i, fig, scat):
        scat.set_offsets(([math.cos(math.radians(i))*5, math.sin(math.radians(i))*5], [math.cos(math.radians(i/2))*10, math.sin(math.radians(i/2))*10], [0, 0]))
        print('Frames: %d' %i)

        return scat*

    fig = plt.figure()

    x = [0]
    y = [0]

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.grid(True, linestyle = '-', color = '0.10')
    ax.set_xlim([-50, 50])
    ax.set_ylim([-50, 50])

    scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c = x)
    scat.set_alpha(0.8)

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs = (fig, scat),
                                   frames = 720, interval = 10)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
import math
def _update_plot(i, fig, scat, l):
        scat.set_offsets(([math.cos(math.radians(i))*5, math.sin(math.radians(i))*5], [math.cos(math.radians(i/2))*10, math.sin(math.radians(i/2))*10], [0, 0]))
        l.set_data(([math.cos(math.radians(i))*5,math.cos(math.radians(i/2))*10],[math.sin(math.radians(i))*5,math.sin(math.radians(i/2))*10]))
        return [scat,l]

fig = plt.figure()

x = [0]
y = [0]

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.grid(True, linestyle = '-', color = '0.10')
ax.set_xlim([-11, 11])
ax.set_ylim([-11, 11])

l, = plt.plot([],[], 'r--', zorder=1)
scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c = x, zorder=2)
scat.set_alpha(0.8)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs = (fig, scat, l),
                               frames = 720, interval = 10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! thank you so much this has helped out loads. Diziet Asahi

Comment: You're welcome. If that answered your question, consider accepting the answer using the check mark on the left to mark the question was closed